Issues with Nginx Proxy and Angular App: CSS and JS Not Loading Due to MIME Type Error
I'm encountering a problem with my Nginx proxy configuration and Angular application setup. Here's the context and the issue I'm facing:
Setup:
I'm using Nginx Proxy Manager as my main Nginx proxy.
I have a host configured with a custom location: name.domain.at/app.
This location is supposed to proxy requests to another Nginx server container with the IP address 172.21.0.1 and port 28007.
Angular Application:
My Angular application is built with the base href set to /app/.
Problem:
While the index.html of the Angular application loads correctly, my CSS and JS files are not loading.
The browser console shows the error: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
Possible Causes and Steps Taken:
I suspect that there might be an issue with how Nginx is handling the path or MIME types for the static assets.
I have checked the configuration of both the Nginx Proxy Manager and the backend Nginx container, but I am unsure if they are correctly set up to serve the static assets for the Angular app.
Nginx Proxy Server Configuration;

Second Nginx Configuration:
server {
    listen 28007;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        root /container/home/www/my-weblclient/browser;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

Question:
How can I adjust my Nginx configurations to ensure that CSS and JS files are correctly served with the proper MIME types?
Are there any specific changes needed in the proxy configuration or backend Nginx settings to resolve the MIME type issue?
MIME Type Configuration: I tried setting up the MIME types explicitly in the Nginx configuration.
Path Variations: I experimented with different path formats for /app/—both with and without the trailing slash.

This Devops question, not about programming

this is usually a routing issue where you are returning HTML.  (index.html in this case?) Check the paths manually in the browser's URL bar.  It's usually got nothing to do with MIME types.  (the browser just infers those from extension)

@browsermator yes index.html of the angular app. If I inspect the network tab i get a 200 on every request.

I don't know nginx, but seems like this could be routing all relative root paths to index.html.
